# How can I convert PNG to GIF keeping the transparency?

Tags: delphi, graphics, png, gif

How can I convert PNG to GIF keeping the transparency?

I would have hoped that using the Assign( ) method would work but it doesn't seem to migrate transparency.  In the GIF, it's represented as black.

```
    png:=TPngImage.Create;
    try
      png.LoadFromFile(sFile);
      // comes from file:  png.TransparencyMode;
      // comes from file:  png.Transparent

      // didn't help:  gif.Transparent:=true;

      gif.Assign(png);

      // didn't help:  gif.Transparent:=true;

      gif.SaveToFile('e:\tmp\out.gif');
    finally
      png.Free;
    end;
```

I haven't found a way to handle this in Delphi...

thanks!

Comment: PNG uses alpha transparency. How do you want to deal with that?

Comment: I just want it to look the same as the GIF did.

Comment: Well, it's not going to look the same. PNG supports full RGB color with alpha transparency. GIF has 256 colour palette and per pixel transparency. One has to ask why you are choosing to use such an inferior image format. It's 2015!

Comment: try libs: GraphicEx, Graphics32.org, Vampyre Imaging

Comment: @DavidHeffernan PNG supports 8-bit indexed mode too

Comment: I had internally standardized the picture storage to GIF.  Typically, it would be used for putting a company logo into a report.

Comment: Had looked in Graphics32 directly but didn't see a way to do this.  It may well be that it can do it but I don't recognize it or don't know that function _____ is intended for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Arioch magic application of libraries won't bridge format mismatch

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My bad! I read he wants to convert GIF-to-PNG, that could be easily done since PNG (sans animation) is feature-wise a superset of GIF (and aPNG and MNG probably are strict supersets).

PNG to GIF indeed only can be done in simplistic cases

Comment: @X-Ray sorry, I misread... Well, introduce the requirement to PNG that it would be in 256-colors mode and only use 100% or 0% transparency with no semi-transparent areas. Otherwise it would require manual work of artists instead

Comment: It's really about time to stop using GIF. It's dragging you down.

Comment: thank you for your answers.  here's my thought now:  migrate to PNG for the internal storage since @Arioch says GIF-to-PNG is simple.  Then I just need to ensure Fast Reports will handle this correctly.

Comment: Only use of GIF these days is for animation - which is still a pretty outdated method.

Comment: @JerryDodge sometimes it compresses better than PNG (even PNG 8bit). But in general I agree, aPNG and MNG make GIF obsolete even for animation

Comment: @Arioch And that compression also tends to result in poor quality. It really depends on what the image is. A photo, for example, would be horrible in a GIF, but a 2-3 color logo, sure, it may compress better.  I personally prefer vector format though.

Comment: @X-Ray FastReports can handle PNGs without problems.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan migrated to use PNG.  will you put that as an answer or shall I?  (to close this question down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to transfer an image from a PNG to a GIF. However, I don't recommend that you do so. The GIF format is substantially less capable than PNG. PNG supports RGBA color channels and partial transparency. GIF uses a 256 color palette and no support for partial transparency.

There are many libraries available that will make the best of a bad job and attempt to produce a GIF image that is close to the PNG image, but information will be lost.

The GIF format dates from the late 1980s and time has moved on. It has long since served its purpose. PNG is modern, capable and well supported. If it is possible to do so you should switch from GIF to using PNG.

Comment: Not specifically directed at you, but this is a contradiction when one begins referring to animations: "The GIF format dates from the late 1980s"... yet we are still using GIF for animations and our browser developers are too stubborn and conflicted to agree on anything else.

Comment: @oldmud0 OK, I wasn't thinking of animated GIFs when I wrote this.  It's a fair point.  I don't think we are too far away from being able to use HTML5 video in this space though.

Comment: It is already being used for some longer animations where lossy is fine (WebM), but for when lossless is needed (or your images are very tiny), there's really no drop-in replacement to GIF which only has 1-bit transparency.